# Create footprints from a directory of GeoTIFF images in QGIS without loading them as layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

My images are stored in a directory. And it's GBs of data. I want to know the way to create footprints of these images without having to pull them into QGIS individually.

Is there a way by which these images in folders can be read by the system and footprints created automatically?

Answer (score 8):

You could use 'Tile Index' from QGIS menu: Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Tile Index... or just type 'Tile Index' in to the status bar in the bottom left of your QGIS-Window. After providing the directory with your images you will get a vector file with bounding boxes of all files. The Attribute-Table will contain the name and the paths to every single file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess the solution works well. Thanks a lot 

Comment: Good! So you could mark the answer as 'accepted' ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use gdaltindex https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltindex.html from command line. Basic command is simply

```
gdaltindex my_index.shp *.tif
```

Gdaltindex writes rectangles, minimum bounding boxes, of the image footprints. If your images are not regular and north oriented the rectangles are not the same as the footprints. Depending on your use case the index may be accurate enough but the rectangles may overlap even the corresponding images don't really overlap.

Answer (score 0):

(I didnt know of tile index before, when I created this script. And it hangs when I try on the folder below). You can also use pyqgis:

```
import os
rasterfolder = r'/home/bera/Drives/ssd1/1975/67_5/'

rasterlist = [] #A list to store the raster layers in
for root, folder, files in os.walk(rasterfolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.tif'): #I have tif files
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            layer = QgsRasterLayer(fullname, file) #Create a layer
            if layer.isValid():
                rasterlist.append(layer) #Append to list

#Create polygon layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs={}&index=yes".format(rasterlist[0].crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('rastername', QVariant.String)]) #Add a field to hold raster name
vl.updateFields()

for r in rasterlist:
    new_geometry = QgsGeometry.fromRect(r.extent())
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(new_geometry)
    f.setAttributes([r.name()])
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image]